# Create new variable equal to lookup value

Tags: r

I have a dataset:

```
> d <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017/01/01"), as.Date("2017/03/01"), by = "month")
> df <- data.frame(x1 = d, x2 = rev(d), x3 = 1:3)
> df
       x1         x2    x3
1 2017-01-01 2017-03-01  1
2 2017-02-01 2017-02-01  2
3 2017-03-01 2017-01-01  3
```

I would like to create a new variable, x4, which is equal to x3 when x1 == x2.

So far this is the best solution I have, which is a little cryptic.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% mutate(x4 = max( x3 * (x1 == x2) ) )
      x1         x2     x3 x4
1 2017-01-01 2017-03-01  1  2
2 2017-02-01 2017-02-01  2  2
3 2017-03-01 2017-01-01  3  2
```

Is there a more efficient or more readable approach out there?

Comment: I don't understand the logic of the desired output. Shouldn't row 2 of `x4` be `2` and everything else `NA` since `x1 != x2` for rows 1 and 3?

Comment: No, I'm trying to copy the value of X3 in February to all values of X4.

Comment: Isn' this just `df %>% mutate(x4 = x3[x1 == x2])`?

Comment: Yes, nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we look for an efficient solution, then we can use `data.table` assignment in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[x1 == x2, x4 := max(x3) ]
df
#           x1         x2 x3 x4
#1: 2017-01-01 2017-03-01  1 NA
#2: 2017-02-01 2017-02-01  2  2
#3: 2017-03-01 2017-01-01  3 NA
```

and if we don't need the `NA` values, it is

```
setDT(df)[, x4 := max(x3[x1==x2])]
df
#           x1         x2 x3 x4
#1: 2017-01-01 2017-03-01  1  2
#2: 2017-02-01 2017-02-01  2  2
#3: 2017-03-01 2017-01-01  3  2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, x4 = max(x3[x1 == x2]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the max() necessary here?

Comment: I think it depends. Since there may be multiple values of x3 where x1 == x2 you would have to decide if you want the max value or not.